# GORM grails schema generation default data

Tags: grails, grails-orm

GORM is clever enough to generate your SQL database schema as you run the app. But how can I get it to populate it with default records at the same time? e.g. reference data or whatever. Spring Boot mentions something about having a data.sql on your classpath, which sounds like the kind of thing needed.

Comment: I now realise the correct way to do this is in Bootstrap.groovy https://guides.grails.org/creating-your-first-grails-app/guide/index.html#bootstrap

Comment: There is a size limitation on this  file - you can't import tonnes of data by declarations in this file, but what you can do is point it to a service which parses a file and imports as an example